# pymongo result to String

Tags: python, string, dictionary, pymongo

I do a Python pymongo find_one, and get a Dict back, but all I want is a string.

I am lost.  Is anyone able to help?  I really want `ABCDEF` into a String

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['test-database-b']
toArd = db.toArd
myDict = toArd.find_one({u'processed': False})
print myDict
```

Gives this:  `{u'_id': ObjectId('5238273074f8edc6a20c48fe'), u'Command': u'ABCDEF', u'processed': False}`

But really, all I want is `ABCDEF` in a string.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Gives this: {u'_id': ObjectId('5238273074f8edc6a20c48fe'), u'Command':
>   u'ABCDEF', u'processed': False}
>
> But really, all I want is ABCDEF in a string.

What you get is a dictionary, you simply need to fetch what you want from it

```
print myDict[ u'Command']
```